# Assuming p $\to$ (q OR r) and p $\to$ (q OR NOT r), prove p $\to$ q

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, proof-explanation

So I've been trying to figure out how to prove this statement:

> Assuming p $\to$ (q OR r) and p $\to$ (q OR NOT r), prove p $\to$ q.

This is about as far as I got:

1. p → (q OR r)         // Given
2. p → (q OR NOT r)     // Given
3. p                    // Given (I assume that p must exist in order to prove that p → q)
4. q OR r               // 1, 3, modus ponens
5. q OR NOT r           // 2, 3, modus ponens
6. (q OR r) AND (q OR NOT r)    // 4, 5, conjunction

I'm not sure if I'm on the right track, and even if I am, I don't know how to proceed... Could I get a hint? Thanks in advance!

Comment: \to gives a one lined arrow, \implies gives a two-lined arrow (remember that you have to surround MathJax with $ signs to work -- also MathJax is just web-enabled LateX)

Answer (score 1):

So far so good....you've arrived at:

$(6)\quad  (q \lor r)\land (q\lor \lnot r)\tag{correct}$

Your next step, by using the *distributive property* of "or" over $\land$, we have

$$(7) \quad q\lor (r \land \lnot r)\tag{from (6) Distributive property} $$

$$(8)\quad q \lor (F)\tag{from (7) contradiction}$$

$$(9) \quad q\tag{from (8)}$$
$$(10)\quad  p\rightarrow q \;\;(3, 9)\tag{conditional introduction}$$